# ionic 4: <ion-reorder> not working as expected

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, reorderlist

i'm working with ionic 4 angular 7. I'm using `<ion-reorder>` to reorder list.  Drag n Drop works for the first time fine but when I release the `click`, item got stuck. After first reorder everything freezes. And I'm unable to attempt reorder for the second time.

Here my .html file

```
<ion-list lines="none">
      <ion-reorder-group disabled="false">
        <ion-reorder>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail no-margin item-start>
              <img src="../assets/images/5.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <div class="pl-2">
              <h5 no-margin>Multan</h5>
              <p no-margin>Historical place...</p>
            </div>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
              <ion-button>
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder>
        <ion-reorder>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail no-margin item-start>
              <img src="../assets/images/5.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <div class="pl-2">
              <h5 no-margin>Multan</h5>
              <p no-margin>Historical place...</p>
            </div>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
              <ion-button>
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder>
        <ion-reorder>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail no-margin item-start>
              <img src="../assets/images/5.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <div class="pl-2">
              <h5 no-margin>Multan</h5>
              <p no-margin>Historical place...</p>
            </div>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
              <ion-button>
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder>
        <ion-reorder>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail no-margin item-start>
              <img src="../assets/images/5.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <div class="pl-2">
              <h5 no-margin>Multan</h5>
              <p no-margin>Historical place...</p>
            </div>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
              <ion-button>
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder>
      </ion-reorder-group>
    </ion-list>
```

When I drag n Drop Item. It get stuck when I drop it. After this, everything freezes.

Any Help...?

[image]

I'm using

Ionic: 4.10.2
Angular: 7.3.0

Comment: Sorry @PeterHaddad the link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you need to store your data in a variable and ngFor on these data to build your reorder items.

```
this.items: Array<img: string; title: string; description: string; icon: 
string> = [yourArrayOfObjects];
```

I think then you need to catch the ionItemReorder event like this

```
<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)" disabled="false">
```

and in your .ts the reorderItems() function could be

```
reorderItems(ev) {
    const itemMove = this.items.splice(ev.detail.from, 1)[0];
    this.items.splice(ev.detail.to, 0, itemMove);
    ev.detail.complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Although as per ionic documentation, this should work with one statement: this.items = ev.detail.complete(this.items); but it's not working.

Comment: You can add type context to the event in typescript: 


`import { ItemReorderEventDetail } from '@ionic/core';`

`reorderItems(ev: CustomEvent<ItemReorderEventDetail>);`

Comment: I was missing the 'complete' call. Thanks

Comment: I added a (click) event instead of (ionItemReorder) event. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The key here is to complete the event and you have to do it manually. So the `ionItemReorder` event callback is a must. So something as simple as this should do the trick:

**Typescript** :

```
    public onItemReorder({ detail }) {
       detail.complete(true);
    }
```

**HTML** :

`<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="onItemReorder($event)" [disabled]="false">`

Answer (score 1):

ionic4 version:

html code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>INCLUDE</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorder($event)" [disabled]="false">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let accessory of accessories">
                <ion-label>{{accessory}}</ion-label>
                <ion-reorder></ion-reorder>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-reorder-group>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

typescript code:

```
accessories = ['test', 'test1', 'test2'];

reorder(event) {
        const itemToMove = this.accessories.splice(event.detail.from, 1)[0];
        this.accessories.splice(event.detail.to, 0, itemToMove);
}
```

This will never throw any type of error, it works. I am 100% sure, have used 3-4 times. I hope, this will also help you.

Comment: this required the ```event.accessories.complete();``` after the final splice

Answer (score 1):

```
  <ion-list >
              <ion-item-group (ionItemReorder)="reorder($event)"  reorder='true' >
                <ion-item *ngFor="let item of file_uri" (click)="openSubMenu(item.bunch)" style="background-color: #F0F0F0">
                <ion-avatar item-left >
                  <img src="assets/{{item.bunch}}.svg">
                </ion-avatar>  

                  <h2 color="primary_secound">{{item.bunch}}
                  </h2>
                  <p>Click To See Menu of {{item.bunch}} 
                  </p>

                  <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" item-right></ion-icon>

                </ion-item>
              </ion-item-group>
              </ion-list> 
reorder(event) {
        const itemToMove = this.file_uri.splice(event.from, 1)[0];
        this.file_uri.splice(event.to, 0, itemToMove);
    }
```

Comment: Try to add some description about your answer. It will help others to easily catch your code.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular - Ionic - Typescript

in HTML file/Code:

```
<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)" disabled="false">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of yourArray">
         <ion-label> {{ item.name }} </ion-label>
         <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
    </ion-item>
</ion-reorder-group>
```

Controller or .ts Code:

```
  reorderItems(ev): void {
    const itemMove = this.yourArray.splice(ev.detail.from, 1)[0];
    this.yourArray.splice(ev.detail.to, 0, itemMove);
    ev.detail.complete();
  }
```

As per the above example, If you did not add reorderItems() in your controller it will not work. you can change function name as you like.